# How to remove trailing CRUD names from django-restframework yasg redoc schema?

Tags: django-rest-framework, redoc

Is there a way to remove the CRUD names like `_list` and `_create` from the API endpoint titles in the left panel?

[image]

```
djangorestframework==3.12.4
drf-yasg==1.20.0
```

Comment: Also facing this issue. I switched to using the 'swagger' view instead, as it gave slightly better endpoint names